# Error in reading and writing csv file in python

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I have a python code where I am reading data from csv file and pushing its contents to MySQL. I am getting the above mentioned error. Here is the code:

```
csv_data = csv.reader('ga_python_data.csv')
csv_data = csv.reader('data.csv')

for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO new (date,sessions) VALUES (%s, %s)',*row)
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string.
```

Comment: What "above mentioned error"?

Comment: Show the error with a full traceback.

Comment: At the very least we need an idea of what the error is...

Comment: self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
Is the error.

Comment: `csvfile.close()` is not needed. `csvfile` will be automatically closed when it leaves the scope of the `with` statement.

Comment: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape. Is the new error I got.

Comment: Question modified @Martin Evans.

Comment: Question modified @cdarke

Comment: Question modified @trotta

Comment: Currently you have one argument `row` but you have two `%s` specifiers. You need to add the second argument after `row`.

Comment: Question modified @Mureinik

Comment: @MartinEvans I am still getting the same error. And I have added some more information regarding the code

Comment: Question modified @Henry

Comment: What does `row` contain? Please give an example.

Comment: It contains 2 columns date and sessions. Date and sessions of that particular day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you have one argument row but you have two `%s` specifiers. You need to add the second argument after row. In your case you are reading entries from a CSV file. In theory there should always be two items per row, but if your CSV file has an empty row, or if one of the rows is missing an entry it will cause problems. This script only accepts rows which contain two values:

```
import MySQLdb
import csv

# ...first connect to db and create cursor

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f_data:
    csv_data = csv.reader(f_data)
    #header = next(csv_data)  # optionally skip over a header line 

    for row in csv_data:
        if len(row) == 2:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO new (date,sessions) VALUES (%s, %s)', tuple(row))
```

Lastly, it is important to ensure you open the file correctly. In Python 2.x, the file must be opened in binary mode. If you are using Python 3.x, you will need to change the line as follows:

```
with open('data.csv', 'r', newline='') as f_data:
```

Answer (score 0):

@MartinEvans comment about missing argument is correct:

> Currently you have one argument row but you have two %s specifies. You need to add the second argument after row.

If `row` contains two strings you want to insert you need to unpack it like this `*row`

In that case you code would look like:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO metrics VALUES ('%s', '%s')", *row)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because your row is a single string, and you're trying to paste in two strings. You should probably do something like:

```
tokens=row.split(',')
cursor.execute(....., tokens[0],tokens[1])
```